# Django logging of custom management commands

Tags: python, django, logging

I have an app named `main` in my Django project. This app has a several management commands that I want to log, but nothing is showing up in stdout with the following configuration:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'log_to_stdout': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': sys.stdout,
            },
        },
    'loggers': {
        'main': {
            'handlers': ['log_to_stdout'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried using `my_project.main` as well, but that didn't work either.  I'm using 1.3.0 final.

Comment: what command are you using to log output?

Comment: I've tried `logging.info` and `logging.debug`, but neither of them work.  After writing this question, I noticed that `logging.warn` *does* give me a print to stdout.

Comment: Sounds like your log level isn't being set properly.  Try something like this https://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2017/03/08/logging-verbosity-managment-commands.html if you want to tie it to the `verbosity` flag.

Comment: For others who may be reading this...  The root logger defaults to the "warning" level, so likely the logger being used was propagating to the root logger (or was the root logger) and not the "main" one being declared here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you need to namespace your logger. currently you are logging to the root logger, which isn't caught by your handler, which is looking for `main`

rather than `logging.debug("message")`, you want

```
logger = logging.getLogger('main')
logger.debug("message")
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting "stream" to sys.stdout is not necessary. However, you should define a formatter:

Example:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'log_to_stdout': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            },
        },
    'loggers': {
        'main': {
            'handlers': ['log_to_stdout'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried by copy-pasting your example code verbatim but still, I get nothing to stdout. *However*, when I insert `logging.warn('foo')` as the first statement, I do get a print in stdout. `logging.info` and `logging.debug` still don't work.

Answer (score -5):

If you are enrolling these custom commands with cron, you can "force" logging by just redirecting output to a text file.

```
* 12 * * * python /path/to/my/custom/command.py >> /path/to/my/logfile.txt
```

This will run a cron job at 12am every morning, and anything directed to stdout (like python print statements) will be dumped into this text file, concatenated on any existing text in the logfile.

If you're not using cron, just create a single shell script that runs all the scripts you need to run and manually direct them to the logfiles you want.

```
python /path/to/my/custom/command.py >> /path/to/my/logfile.txt
```

...and so on.

Comment: Thanks, but this is the method I used before. I'm trying to do the right thing and use Django's "built-in" logging capabilities if possible.

Comment: Fair enough. Hopefully someone will step in and help you with this; I'm primitive and use shell redirection. :)